# I am not getting the output for this code(Reversing a string). Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: c, function, reverse, definition, c-strings

I started writing this code for reversing a string. But in the output it only asks for input and then it exits. It would be of great help if anyone told me the simplest solution for this problem.

```
char* ptr;

//main function
{   

    int i;
    char *OriginalString1,*OriginalString2;
    OriginalString1=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));


    //Input string
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s", OriginalString1);
    strcpy(OriginalString2, OriginalString1);
    free(OriginalString1);

    char reversestring[sizeof(OriginalString2)];
    char revstr[sizeof(OriginalString2)];
    Reverse_String(OriginalString2, reversestring);
    for(i=0;ptr!=reversestring-1; i++)
    {
        revstr[i]=*(ptr-1);
        ptr--;
    }
    revstr[i+1]='\0';
    printf("\nThe reverse string is: %s \n", revstr); 


}

//Function to reverse the string

char *Reverse_String(char *OriginalString,char reversestring[])
{

    int i;
    ptr=reversestring;
    for(i=0; *(OriginalString+i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        *ptr = *(OriginalString+i);
        ptr++;
    }
    *ptr='\0';
    return (char*)ptr;
}
```

I expect the output to be 'ih' for the input 'hi'. But I only get to give the input and no output comes.

Comment: Your code seems to be *copying* the string (rather convolutedly), not reversing it.

Comment: Before the strcpy, you need to also malloc() some space for OriginalString2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement

```
strcpy(OriginalString2, OriginalString1);
```

does not make sense because the pointer `OriginalString2` has indeterminate value. It was not initialized.

And these declarations

```
char reversestring[sizeof(OriginalString2)];
char revstr[sizeof(OriginalString2)];
```

do not make sense because there is used the size of a pointer not the size of the string pointed to by the pointer.

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you could write

```
char reversestring[strlen(OriginalString2) + 1];
```

Also it is a bad idea that the function `Reverse_String` uses the global variable `ptr`. You could define it within the function.

And this loop

```
for(i=0; *(OriginalString+i) != '\0'; i++)
{
    *ptr = *(OriginalString+i);
    ptr++;
}
```

does not copy the original string in the reverse order.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_copy( const char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s1 );

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < n; i++)
    {
        s2[i] = s1[n - i - 1];
    }

    s2[i] = '\0';

    return s2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char s1[] = "Hello Vijay";
    char s2[sizeof( s1 )];

    reverse_copy( s1, s2 );

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The porgram output is

```
Hello Vijay
yajiV olleH
```

If you do not want (or are not allowed) to use the standard C function `strlen` and want to use pointers then the function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse_copy( const char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    const char *in = s1;

    while ( *in != '\0' ) ++in;

    char *out = s2;

    while ( in != s1 )
    {
        *out++ = *--in;
    }

    *out = '\0';

    return s2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char s1[] = "Hello Vijay";
    char s2[sizeof( s1 )];

    reverse_copy( s1, s2 );

    puts( s1 );
    puts( s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as above

```
Hello Vijay
yajiV olleH
```

Comment: So.. does making it as " char reversestring[strlen(OriginalString2)*sizeof(char)] " help?

Comment: @Vijay You have to reserve one byte for the terminating zero char reversestring[strlen(OriginalString2)  + 1];

Answer (score -1):

You are using malloc & free wrong, you called free on the buffer that holds your original string. You can't free originalString1 until you are done using it.

Below I have provided a standard way of reversing a string, but normally the reverse would be done in place.

```
// Macros to make reading strings from command line into buffer more safe
#define SCANF_CFORMAT(S) "%" #S "c"
#define CSIZE(S) SCANF_CFORMAT(S)

// Size of input string, excluding NUL terminator
#define BUFSIZE 100

//Function to reverse the string
char *Reverse_String(char *originalString, char *reverseString)
{
    uint32_t i, n=0;

    // Sanity check input and output buffers
    if (!originalString || ! reverseString){ 
        return NULL;
    }

    // Find length of original string -- could have used strlen()
    while (originalString[n] != '\0' && n < BUFSIZE){
        n++;
    }

    reverseString[n+1] = '\0'; // NUL terminate reversed string.

    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        reverseString[n-i-1] = originalString[i];
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int i;

    char originalString[BUFSIZE+1];
    char reverseString[BUFSIZE+1];

    // Input string
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf(CSIZE(BUFSIZE), originalString);

    Reverse_String(originalString, reverseString);

    printf("\nThe reverse string is: %s \n", reverseString);
}
```